# Google Cloud Platform : Compute Engine Instance File Download Fail

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Currently, all companies' services are distributed through GCP's Compute Engine after creating an instance.

I had to download files from my instance every month, so I downloaded them from my instance

I used to download it like this
(Example: suppose downloaded file is /home/users/abc.sql)

1. Enter root permission in /home/users
2. Click the File Download button to specify the path to the file you want to download: /home/users/abc.sql
3. Create abc.sql in my MacBook download folder when download is complete
4. The end.

I downloaded it through this method up to 5 days ago and used this method as it is.

But I had to download it today, so I tried the same method

Item sent. Directory: /home/users/abc.sql

It just pops up and doesn't download to my PC.

My MacBook has an OS of Sonoma 14.0
Not working on MacBook, I tried on Windows desktop and found the same issue that was not downloaded to PC.

Of course, I tried to download it after escaping from the root authority, but the same phenomenon occurs.

How do I download a file from an instance to my computer??

Comment: Can you try checking your instance connectivity. You can SSH into an instance to verify its status and network connectivity. Check your project’s firewall rules to make sure they allow SSH and SCP traffic. You can also refer to this [link](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-download-a-file-from-an-ec2-instance-to-your-local-computer/). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Until now, I've done SSH connections through my browser
In the process of reflecting the link you gave me
The public keysh permission denied keeps happening, so I'll try this first and share the results again.

Comment: I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.